# How to change the color of a tooltip using the Pmw module in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip, pmw

I am trying to make a tooltip in Tkinter by using the Pmw module. When the user hovers the mouse over the button I want to display a tooltip with a black background and white text but I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from tkinter import *
import Pmw

root = Tk()
Pmw.initialise(root)

# Create some random widget
button = Button(root, text=" This is a Test", pady=30)
button.pack(pady=10)

# create balloon object and bind it to the widget
balloon = Pmw.Balloon(root)
balloon.bind(button, "Text for the tool tip")

mainloop()
```

How would I go about changing the text color and background color of the tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the label component of the tooltip using `balloon.component("label")` then use `config` on that label.

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
import Pmw

root = Tk()
Pmw.initialise(root)

# Create some random widget
button = Button(root, text=" This is a Test", pady=30)
button.pack(pady=10)

# create balloon object and bind it to the widget
balloon = Pmw.Balloon(root)
balloon.bind(button, "Text for the tool tip")

lbl = balloon.component("label")
lbl.config(background="black", foreground="white")
# Pmw.Color.changecolor(lbl, background="black", foreground="white")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please do not use `wildcard import`, instead use alias like - `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @PCM OP used wildcard import. I just copied it. Besides, this is quite a small program and will not cause much of an issue.

Comment: At least you can tell them not to use it. It is bad practice to use wildcard imports

Comment: @PCM every day many beginners use wildcard imports it's not possible to tell everyone not to do so. It will also be annoying to many other who reads the answer. As they progress they will definitely learn the best practices.

Comment: it showing me 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pmw'' after installing Pmw also @Art

Comment: @SanghamitraLahiri check if you are using virtual env or something and ensure you have installed it in the right venv.